# How do you manipulate Polygons in Android?

Tags: java, android, animation, kotlin, graphics

How do I draw a Polygon in android whose height can be manipulated at each end separately.
This is my image : [image]

Based on 2 run time values(speed,fuel) I want to manipulate each side of the Polygon. 
How can this be done? I have worked with SVGs but I'm not able to find a way to manipulate them at run time.

Comment: The only way I could think of is an algorithm which calculates each pixel of a frame in RendearScript and storing the result in a Bitmap for further use. This would be a very dynamic approach without the need of libraries or any external API.

Comment: Drawing polygons of any shape can be accomplished easily with the use of a custom `View` subclass and `Canvas.drawPath()`.

Comment: @greeble31 That's what I'm doing now, but was hoping there was another way.